# CPTDecimalFromFloat and other Primitive to Decimal Conversion Crash

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using CorePlot latest version downloaded from github, I was trying to play around with the sample [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2), the PieCharts loads without any problem but when I try to move to 2nd or 3rd Tab, i.e.BarGraph or ScatterPlot the app crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS), also no log is generated in console.
For both the BarGraph and ScatterPlot Tab the app crashes at a same type of line i.e. wherever the CPTDecimalFromFloat or CPTDecimalFromDouble is being called.

Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There were some API changes in 2.0 (currently the latest version). Any property or method that took an `NSDecimal` value in earlier versions now takes an `NSNumber`. See this [wiki page](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Core-Plot-API-Changes-Between-Versions-1.x-and-2.x) for details.

Comment: First of all many thanks @Eric Sir for writing and making it Open source. Seems a lot changes done in 2.0, I will download the latest version and check once again. 
Thanks again!!